# Was Lord Krishna himself Vishnu or not?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhagavata-purana, avatars

Lord Krishna was an avatar of Lord Vishnu but once I have heard that one day Lord Krishna and Arjuna went to Ksheera Sagara to see Lord Vishnu and they had met him. So,if Lord Krishna was a form of Vishnu,how can he meet Vishnu?

Comment: Even when Vishnu descends to earth as Avatar, Narayana still resides in Vaikuntam.

Answer (score 1):

Bhagavan Krishna was a vibhava avatara of Sriman Narayana. It is not that when Bhagavan descends to bhu-lokam in one of his avatarams Vaikuntham suddenly becomes vacant- all of Bhagavan's avatarams issue forth from Sriman Narayana who remains in Vaikuntham.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! You should cite sources.

Comment: @AnujGhai Well put. There is no limit to That Itself. Sri Krishna himself demonstrated this by appearing as the limitless `leaves of universes`.